# ExpandableListAdapter using Nested LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android, linkedhashmap

Good morning guys,

I need to build a custom adapter using the following nested linked hashmap: `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Class<?>>>`. I am extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and have implemented the methods required. I have written the following code to get the group names from the `LinkedHashMap`:

```
    private Context context;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Class<?>>> menuOptions;

    public customMenuAdapter(Context context, LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Class<?>>> menuOptions)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuOptions = menuOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return this.menuOptions.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return this.menuOptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String gpsMenuGroupTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater gpsGroupInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = gpsGroupInflater.inflate(R.layout.gps_menu_list_header, null);
        }

        TextView gpsListHeaderText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gps_menu_list_header);
        gpsListHeaderText.setText(gpsMenuGroupTitle);

        return convertView;
    }
```

I have to get the child items from the nested `LinkedHashMap` and I have no idea how to do so.

In the `getChild` method do I simply `return this.menuOptions.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);`? Should I create a field and extract the nested `LinkedHashMap` into it?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I resolved this issue and it was quite simple. I created a my own custom adapter which receives the `LinkedHashMap`. I extract the keys into a `List` which is used as the Group Headings. The adapter then extracts the nested `LinkedHashMap`, the keys are used as the child menu item names.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to keep header data and child data in separate list. What i like to do is, i have child and header data in separate reference. So my constructor look like this

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context _context, List<String> _headerDataList, HashMap<String, List<String>> _childDataList)
    {
        this._context = _context;
        this._headerDataList = _headerDataList;
        this._childDataList = _childDataList;

    }
```

So in the get child you do this.

```
@Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return _childDataList.get(_headerDataList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }
```

Comment: This is what I did initially but my employer is insisting that we use the nested `LinkedHashMap`. We are planning to scale later and doing it that way makes scaling much easier in theory but makes creating the initial "superclasses" much more difficult and I am stuck on this. Obiviously putting the code in the the `LinkedHashMap` is not too difficult but working with it in the Adapter is then more complex

Comment: So i think this will be nested LinkedHashMap. Then in your getchild() you will be doing something like this. 
String key = menuoption.get(groupPosition)
menuOptions.get(key).get(key).getClass();